# Bootstrap - Запретить расширение контейнера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Имеется фрагмент кода:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="article"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В блоке с `id="article"` содержимое формируется динамически. При этом блок растягивается по горизонтали, если содержимое слишком большое по ширине. Как запретить растяжение по горизонтали сверх ширины, устанавливаемой классом `col-`?

**Уточнение:**

1. В содержимом блока `article` могут быть таблицы, ограничение с помощью `max-width` для них не работает. Пример:

```html
<table cols="6" rules="NONE" border="0" cellspacing="0" height="611" width="648">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="86">
      <col width="86">
        <col width="129">
          <col width="115">
            <col width="86">
              <col width="117">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;" align="CENTER" height="19" valign="TOP">2016-11-10</td>
      <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;" align="CENTER">36,00</td>
      <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;" align="CENTER">1&nbsp;230&nbsp;933</td>
      <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;" align="CENTER">44&nbsp;313&nbsp;588,00</td>
      <td align="LEFT">
        <br>
      </td>
      <td align="LEFT">
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

2. Пытался реализовать вариант с использованием wrapper-блока внутри `article`. Однако, применение стиля `max-width: 100%` не работает (т.к. внешний контейнер не имеет фиксированной ширины), а задавать конкретное значение для max-width нет возможности (оно неизвестно).

Comment: А вы можете добавить код где у вас проблемный `div` расширяется не так как вам хочется? А я затем постараюсь решить вашу проблему.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Добавил пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

стили бутстрапа:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col" id="article"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

стили для контейнера:

```
.col {
  position: relative;
}

.col > *{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: В содержимом блока article могут быть таблицы, ограничение с помощью max-width для них не работает.

Comment: в бутстрапе для этого предусмотрен контейнер с классом .table-responsive